# why can the character's order in regex expression affect sed?

Tags: sed, regex-group

The tv.txt file is as following:

```
mms://live21.gztv.com/gztv_gz 广州台[可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3]
mms://live21.gztv.com/gztv_news 广州新闻台·直播广州(可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3)
mms://live21.gztv.com/gztv_kids 广州少儿台(可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3)
mms://live21.gztv.com/gztv_econ 广州经济台
```

I want to group it into three groups.

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]*)\s([^][()]*)((\(.+\))*|(\[.+\])*)/\3/'  tv.txt
```

got the result:

```
[可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3]    
(可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3)    
(可于Totem/VLC/MPlayer播放，记得把高宽比设置成4:3)
```

When I write it into

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]*)\s([^][()]*)((\(.+\))*|(\[.+\])*)/\3/'  tv.txt
```

It can't work.

The only difference is `[^][()]` and `[^[]()]`; neither of the `[^\[\]()]` ,escape characters can not make it run properly.

I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) rules for getting `]` into a character class are a little arcane, but they make sense when you think about it hard.

For a positive (non-negated) character class, the `]` must be the first character:

```
[]and]
```

This recognizes any character `a`, `n`, `d` or `]` as part of the character class.

For a negated character class, the `]` must be the first character after the `^`:

```
[^]and]
```

This recognizes any character except `a`, `n`, `d` or `]` as part of the character class.

Otherwise, the first `]` after the `[` marks the end of the character class.  Inside a character class, most of the normal regex special characters lose their special meaning, and others (notably `-` minus) acquire special meanings.  (If you want a `-` in a character class, it has to be 'first' or last, where 'first' means 'after the optional `^` and only if `]` is not present'.)

In your examples:

- `[^][()]` — this is a negated character class that recognizes any character except `[`, `]`, `(` or `)`, but
- `[^[]()]` — this is a negated character class that recognizes any character except `[`, followed by whatever `()` symbolizes in the regex family you're using, and `]` which represents itself.